# Getting emulated mobile view of a temporarily changed html page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am using a chrome extension to temporarily change layout of a Google search  webpage. I am changing heading and description of the Advertisements displayed. This part works fine.
Next, I need to take screenshot of desktop, tablet and mobile views. getting desktop view is pretty straight. However, for tab/mobile view if I uses any of mobile emulator, or dev console, they refresh the html page before providing the mobile/tab emulation. This results in loosing the html page changes that were done by the chrome extension.
Is there are way to use mobile emulation without reloading/refreshing the page, so that the changes done in html are intact even in tables/mobile views.

Comment: I don't think this would be possible. I'm not 100% certain, so not posting as an answer, but it's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer !
In Dev console, we have the option device toggle(Ctrl+Shift+M)
[image]

This way, temporary DOM changes done in desktop view were intact in mobile view as well.